# WPF Событие Drop вызывается для родительского и дочернего itemscontrol при перетаскивании в дочерний

Tags: wpf, drag-n-drop, itemscontrol

Я делаю проект в WPF, где пользователь может создавать форму заявления перетаскивая элементы внутрь itemscontrol'а, так же у меня есть контрол "группа", который состоит из itemscontrol и label, который может хранить различные элементы. Когда я перетаскиваю элемент в группу, событие Drop вызывается в у группы, и у главного itemscontrol'а и элемент добавляется сразу в два itemscontrol'а. Кажется, что дочерний элемент передает событие Drop в родительский. Как сделать чтобы событие Drop вызывалось именно в элементе, в который происходит перетаскивание?
Пример: [image: Пример]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй

```
e.Handled = true
```

поставить в `OnDrop`.

Таким образом эвент не будет всплывать т.к. он является **bubbling event**.

Если не получится - попробуй добавить эвент `DragOver` и там `e.Handled` выставить в `true`.